# converting mongodb arrays into python arrays

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm writing a code in which i find this kind of database (i'm using pymongo).
How can i attribute these arrays inside the wishlist field to python arrays?

Alternatively, how can i search my database for a value inside an array inside the `wishlist` field. E.g.: i want to find all IDs that have, say, `["feldon","c15", "sp"]` in their `wishlists`

```
{
    "_id" : "david",
    "password" : "azzzzzaa",
    "url" : "url3",
    "old_url" : "url3",
    "new_url" : ["url1", "url2"],
    "wishlist" : [
        ["all is dust", "mm4", "nm"],
        ["feldon", "c15", "sp"],
        ["feldon", "c15", "sp"],
        ["jenara", "shards", "nm"],
        ["rafiq", "shards", "nm"]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) if elements in your sublist and are exactly in the same order.

```
db.collection.distinct("_id", {"wishlist": ["feldon", "c15", "sp"]})
```

If not, you need to use the [`aggregate`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method and the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            {"$setIsSubset": [
                [["feldon","c15", "sp"]], 
                "$wishlist"
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}, 
    {"$group": {
        "_id": None, 
        "ids": {"$push": "$_id"}
    }}
])
```